# extjs how to make text field visible globally

Tags: extjs

```
getLanguageID();   //Trigger when each time page Refresh...

alert("Welcome to Application");

var flag = Ext.getCmp('txthidden').getValue();
if (flag == 1) {
var login_lbl = "ಲಾಗಿನ್";
//-----this label I used for textFild --> fieldLabel: '<b>' + login_lbl + '</b>',
}

if (flag == 2) {
var login_lbl = "Login";
 //-----this label I used for textFild --> fieldLabel: '<b>' + login_lbl + '</b>',
}


var txtLoginName = Ext.create('Ext.form.TextField', {
id: 'txtLoginName ',
name: 'txtLoginName ',
fieldLabel: '<b>' + login_lbl + '</b><b><font color=red>*</font></b>',
anchor: '90%',
readOnly: false,
allowBlank: false
});
 ....
 ....
Ext.onReady(function () {
Ext.QuickTips.init();

var win = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
layout: 'fit',
renderTo: 'loginform',
width: 550,
height: 170,
closable: false,
resizable: false,
plain: true,
border: false,
items: [login]
});
Ext.getCmp('UserNameId').focus(false, 200);
});


function getLanguageID() {
Ext.Ajax.request({

url: '/General/AdministrationDefaultXMLDOM.aspx?qid=111',
success: function (response) {
    var hidden = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
    var Tenor = hidden[0].Language;
  // here Tenor value is fetch from database 1 or 2. that is fine.
    var txthidden = Ext.create('Ext.form.TextField', {
        id: 'txthidden',
        name: 'txthidden',
        hidden: true,
    });
  Ext.getCmp('txthidden').setValue(Tenor);
}
});
}
```

If I use alert("Welcome to Application"); js loads after the flag value fetch from the "txthidden". and gives answer properly..

otherwise js page loads before the value set to the flag... label is "undefined" in the place of "filedLable"

Comment: Ext.ComponentQuery.query("txthidden"][0] or set itemId to component txthidden. Look this http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-id

Comment: Here itemId will be limited to the scope of the panel, as opposed to id which can be used globally.
but here that is not my problem..

Comment: Ext.ComponentQuery.query("txthidden") it's work for me